# Изменение размера ImageView в зависимости от разрешения изображения

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview

Есть `RecyclerView`, в элементы которого мне нужно загружать изображения. На этапе отрисовки элемента я знаю только разрешение картинки (из-за особенностей взаимодействия с сервером само изображение я получаю потом). Поэтому стоит задача назначить размеры для контейнера заранее, чтобы после загрузки картинки элемент не разьехался и не сдвигал остальные данные.

Подскажите, как правильно назначить такие размеры?

Пробовал перевести `px` в `dp` и затем назначить эти значения в `imageView.setLayoutParams(params)`, но результат получается совем неправильный.

Нужно, чтобы изображение занимало ширину такую, как на разметке ниже (в случае если оно горизонтальное), но высотой не больше чем `300dp`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если вам известно разрешение изображения, то ничего никкуда переводить не нужно. в LayoutParams вы указываете все размеры в пикселях, а не в dp. Если хотите указывать в dp, чтобы какие-то константные значения подгонялись под плотности экрана, то количество dp умножайте на `DisplayMetrics.density`, получите число пикселей для текущего экрана

С максимальной высотой чуть сложнее. Вроде если установить высоту через layoutParams она проигнорирует атрибут maxHeight. Я вижу только один вариант: использовать свой перегруженный `ImageView` и в `onMeasure` перехватывать запрос на размеры и подставлять нужную высоту, если запрашиваемая больше.